# Does `jq`'s `walk` have an issue with sorting while walking?

Tags: json, recursion, tree, jq

I have a small `jq` use where I want to reverse sort by a tree's size. I know it's possible with `du -h` and `sort -h` etc. But I'm trying it out with `tree`'s json output and `jq`.

It looks like:

```sh
$ tree -h -pug --du -nA -J perl5 | \
awk -v RS= '{ gsub(/,[[:space:]]*]/, "\n]", $0) }1' | \
jq '
walk(if type == "object" and has("contents")
 then (.contents|sort_by(.size)|reverse)
 else . end)'
jq: error (at <stdin>:65): Cannot index array with string "size"
```

So to unpack this, `awk` is used because the json output of `tree` contains extra commas after the last file or directory in a directory's `contents` array.
Line 65 of the input contains the `report` which looks like:

```
  {"type":"report","size":1310049,"directories":24,"files":15}
```

It doesn't contains `contents` so the `if` should be avoiding it.

Here's some simpler test cases:

```sh
$ echo '
{"a":0, "c":[
  {"a":1, "s":3},
  {"a":2, "s":4}]}' | jq -c '
walk(if type == "object" and has("c") and (.c|length) > 0
 then (.c|sort_by(.s)|reverse)
 else . end)'
[{"a":2,"s":4},{"a":1,"s":3}]
$ echo '
{"a":0, "c":[
  {"a":1,"s":3, "c":[
    {"a":1,"s":5},
    {"a":2,"s":6}]},
  {"a":2,"s":4}]}' | jq -c '
walk(if type == "object" and has("c") and (.c|length) > 0
 then (.c|sort_by(.s)|reverse)
 else . end)'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "s"
```

I'm not sure I understand this error message and what I'm missing about `walk`.

Comment: So basically I had to change `then (.contents|sort_by(.size)|reverse)` to `then .contents|=(sort_by(.size)|reverse)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `walk` in your post is incorrect.

You presumably want to update the value of `.contents`, i.e.:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("contents")
  then .contents |= (sort_by(.size)|reverse)
  else . end)
```

(In the latest (post-1.6) version of jq, you can omit the `else .` clause.)

### p.s.

Version 1.8 of `tree` fixes the trailing-comma issue.

If your `tree` produces invalid JSON when using the -J option, rather than using a generic text-processing tool such as `awk`, it might be better to use a tool such as [hjson](http://hjson.org/) to "sanitize" the pseudo-JSON, e.g.

```
tree .... | hjson -j | jq ...
```

### p.p.s.

To understand why one gets the error when the incorrect expression is used as the argument of `walk`, let's consider the simple test case in the OP, but with an extra `debug` inserted so we can see what's going on:

```
echo '
{"a":0, "c":[
  {"a":1,"s":3, "c":[
    {"a":1,"s":5},
    {"a":2,"s":6}]
  },
  {"a":2,"s":4}]
}' | jq -c '
  walk(if type == "object" and has("c")
       then debug | .c | sort_by(.s) | reverse
       else . end)'
```

(I've left out the `length` check as it just clutters up the code.)

This produces:

```
["DEBUG:",{"a":1,"s":3,"c":[{"a":1,"s":5},{"a":2,"s":6}]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":0,"c":[[{"a":2,"s":6},{"a":1,"s":5}],{"a":2,"s":4}]}]
jq: error (at <stdin>:6): Cannot index array with string "s"
```

Now we can see the problem: the second DEBUG line shows that .c has become a bit of a jumble: the first item is an array.  This is because we have replaced .c with an array. It is for this reason that the attempt to use `sort_by(.s)` is failing.

To understand this more completely, it would be necessary to check the definition of `walk`, which is easily done: you could google `jq "def walk"` or go to the source: [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `hjson`. It doesn't appear to be in mac `brew` though. It can be installed as `hjson-cli` using the `go get` instructions.  I hope you don't mind I edited in my own fixes to the scripts… partially because I want people to understand what the original question was trying to do.